# line_profiler returning no output

Tags: python, macos, profiling

I've installed `line_profiler` using `pip install line_profiler`. I'm on Mac OSX 10.8.5, with Python 2.7.

I run `kernprof -l ~/Desktop/sum.py`, and get

```
(default code output)
Wrote profile results to sum.py.lprof
```

But then running `python -m line_profiler sum.py.lprof` gives me:

```
Timer unit: 1e-06 s
```

and no other output. My program code is here: [sum.py](https://github.com/jbzdarkid/EgyptianFractions/blob/master/sum.py).

Comment: You haven't decorated any of the functions - you need to add `@profile`. See [the README](https://github.com/rkern/line_profiler/blob/master/README.rst).

Comment: And remember to use python setup.py develop if you are trying to make a package XD

Answer (score 3):

Comment by jonrsharpe is correct, I had forgotten to add @profile before function headers.